# Why is $f(z-ia)= f(z+ia)$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $f$ be an entire function on $\mathbb{C}$. Let $g(z)=\overline{f(\bar z)}$. Then which of the following is/are true:

$(1)$ If $f(z) \in \mathbb{R} $  $\forall z\in \mathbb {R}$ then $f(z)=g(z)$

$(2)$ If $f(z)\in \mathbb {R} $  $\forall z\in \{z:im(z)=0\} \cup \{z:im(z)=a\}$ for some $a\gt$0 then  $f(z-ia)=f(z+ia)$ $\forall z\in\mathbb {C}$

$(3)$ If $f(z)\in \mathbb {R} $  $\forall z\in \{z:im(z)=0\} \cup \{z:im(z)=a\}$ for some $a\gt$0 then  $f(z+2ia)=f(z)$ $\forall z\in\mathbb {C}$

$(4)$ If $f(z)\in \mathbb {R} $  $\forall z\in \{z:im(z)=0\} \cup \{z:im(z)=a\}$ for some $a\gt$0 then  $f(z+ia)=f(z)$ $\forall z\in\mathbb {C}$

What I have tried so far:
For $(1)$ it is easy to see that the set $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : f(z)=g(z)\}$ contains $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore by Identity Theorem, $f(z)=g(z)$.

And for part $(4)$ Take a function $f(z)=e^z$ and then we see that $(4)$ is NOT true.

Am I correct?

But I have no idea how to proceed for $(2)$ & $(3)$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As $f(z)$  is entire, write $f(z) = c_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {c_{k} (z-ia)^k} $

Clearly, $f(ia) = c_0 \in R$

From part (a), we get,  $f(z)= \overline {f (\bar {z})} = c_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \overline{{c_{k} (\bar z-ia)^k}} = c_0+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {\bar c_{k} (z+ia)^k} $

In the proof of first part, it can be shown that $\overline{c_k} =c_k$ for if

$\overline{f(z)} =f(z)$ whenever $\bar z = z \implies \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {\overline {b_{k}} z^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {b_{k} z^k}} \implies \overline {b_k}=b_k$

Thus, $f(z+ia)= c_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {c_{k} z^k} = f(z-ia)  $